# Binding array data using knockout.js with html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a cateogory model which I got using knockout.js mapping plugin, see below

var categoriesViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

now this categoriesViewModel  has data like

```
[0]{id=1,name="adventure",description="abc"}

[1]{id=2,name="urban",description="def"}

[2]{id=3,name="romantic",description="ghi"}
```

I want to bind the data with following html markup

```
 <section class="categories">

                <ul class="categories-list">
                    <li class="urban"><a  href="javascript:;"><span>urban living</span></a></li>
                    <li class="adventure"><a href="javascript:;"><span>adventure</span></a></li>
                    <li class="romantic"><a href="javascript:;"><span>romantic</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                    <div class="descr">
                        <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
                        <p data-bind="text: Description"></p>
                    </div>
</section>
```

What I want is that on mouseover on any  tag, related description is show in the p tag and name is show in  tag.

I can bind the data in javascript using

```
ko.applyBindings(categoriesViewModel()[0], $('.categories .descr p').get(0));
```

but here I am using index number like [0], which is kind of hard coded approch so I do not want it like this. what should I do to dynamically bind the data i.e. without specifying index in categoriesViewModel() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you need to do is add a "currentItem" or similar to your view model and then bind your descr div to it (using with). Then you can handle the mouse over on your categories to update the currentItem and it *should* all update automagically.

Also, why not use foreach binding for you categories?

See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/QaYGz/1/

Comment: Please see my comments in reply to twofolwer answer.

Comment: @khurram: If you don't want to use a foreach loop, then don't use it. It was just a suggestion and you should really think about if you can make it work if you expect your list of categories to ever change. Either way, the principle of using a currentItem as I've demonstrated in my jsfiddle is still valid whether you hard code you catergories or use a loop.

Comment: if i do not use loop , how can I bind my categories with <a> tag.

Comment: @khurram: If you want to bind something in a collection not in a loop, then it's easy. You just index it, for example: `text:categories()[0].description`

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<section class="categories">
  <ul class="categories-list" data-bind="foreach: categories">
    <li class="urban"><a href="javascript:;"><span data-bind='text: name, event: { mouseover: function(data, event) { $root.updateDescription($data) }, mouseout: function(data, event) { $root.clearDescription() } }'></span></a></li>                    
  </ul>
  <div class="descr">
    <h3 id="idName" data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p id="idDescription" data-bind="text: Description"></p>
  </div>
</section>

var json = {"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"adventure","description":"abc"},
{"id":"2","name":"urban","description":"def"},
{"id":"3","name":"romantic","description":"ghi"}]};

var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);

model.updateDescription = function(val) {    
    $("#idName").text(val.name());
    $("#idDescription").text(val.description());
}

model.clearDescription = function() {
    $("#idName").text('');
    $("#idDescription").text('');
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNJN5/165/) for testing.

Comment: I can not use the loop because of the specific layout so I want to bind the section to the categories array. I want to bind a category specifically to each item. may be I should bind the description id in the attribute and then use that id but I do no not how to do it. Can you please help me in this ?